# How do I get user's timezone using freegeoip.net's API?

Tags: php, geolocation, timezone

Here's the return from `http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json/178.44.164.112`:

> {"source":"smart-ip.net","host":"178.44.164.112","lang":"en","countryName":"Russia","countryCode":"RU","city":"Orenburg","region":"Orenburg","latitude":"51.7227","longitude":"55.3637",**"timezone":"Europe/Samara"**}

Here's the return from a similar service, `http://freegeoip.net/json/178.44.164.112`:

> {"ip":"178.44.164.112","country_code":"RU","country_name":"Russian Federation","region_code":"30","region_name":"Khabarovsk","city":"Orenburg","zipcode":"","latitude":53.3,"longitude":141.4667,"metro_code":"","areacode":""}

The smart-ip.net service provides me with a timezone (for use with PHP's set_timezone). Freegeoip, however, does not. Is there any way to use freegeoip's data to get the timezone of the user?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that freegeoip.net has time zone data.  However, you can take the latitude and longitude and look up the time zone with [one of the methods described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824).